# Jupyter Lab stalling, ignoring imported packages, and kernel failing

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I was unable to solve the specific issue involving the PY 3.6 environment but was able to get everything running on the base environment so this issue is now closed for me at least.

##############

I have a fresh install of Jupyter lab and Jupyter notebook through a fresh install of anaconda on a brand new machine. I am trying to recreate the setup I had on a previous machine. I created an environment for python 3.6, added my extensions, and opened a previous notebook.

My first cell imports my packages:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader as pdr
```

among others.

Then I pull my data from the server

```
df = pd.read_sql_table('df')
list(df.columns)
```

and then run.

In Jupyter Labs the first first part runs, and the second stalls. When I try running the same thing in Notebook it either stalls with no notice or tells me that the kernel needs to restart and then doesnt complete. If I try rerunning the parts enough I eventually get an error on later cells that pd. is not a thing despite not getting an error earlier that pandas had not imported.

I have completely uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda. I have pip uninstalled and reinstalled jupyter. I cant even find specific error codes or documentation on what the issue is just that the kernel is stalling or restarting.

I have tried copying and pasting the text from the old files into notebooks created in this instance and still no dice. I have no clue what the difference could be between my last set up and this one but something is just not working.

ETA:
No specific error message is being returned most of the time, the process just stops. If I rerun the later cells enough I get the message below but I believe that is because the kernel restarted after importing the packages. `NameError: name 'pd' is not defined`

Python 3.6

JupyterLabs 2.2.6

JupyterNotebook 6.2.0

Windows 10 Home

Comment: Can you add the explicit error message that's being returned to you? And can you add your system details? Your os, version of anaconda, pip, python, and jupyter. This way we can try to replicate your setup

Comment: Added the info to the post; no error messages display for the kernel restart only later on when processes crash because it restarted previously